# Uncaught ReferenceError: getVote is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

When the user clicks on one of the yes/no selections as part of my voting system, my code throws an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getVote is not defined

My index.html looks like this:

```
<div id="poll">
            <form>
                Yes: <input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)"> ❌
                <br>
                No: <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
            </form>
</div>
```

it has highlighted the line with the ❌ next to it.

My javascript file looks like this:

```
function getVote(int) {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    }   
    xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

On click it should call that function, but i don't know why its throwing the error.

**I'm not very experienced with font-end languages, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.**

Comment: That would suggest that `getVote` is not defined in the global scope.

Comment: markup comment: if you're going to use `<form>`, add the rest of its attributes so that form submission still works even with JS disabled. And if you don't want it to ever actually submit a form, don't use `<form>`. Also on a JS note, rather than the legacy `XMLHttpRequest`, consider using the Fetch API, which does not require checking readystate and status on each update. And finally, templating strings are worth it too, so you can just say `poll_vote.php?vote=${int}`, although I'd _strongly_ recommend calling that variable `vote`, or `voteId` or something. "int" is a well defined thing.

Comment: If you are using JSFiddle, CodePen, or some other editor rather than working with files, there is an issue that occurs sometimes where you have to put your JavaScript in a `<script>` tag inside of your HTML rather than putting it in the JavaScript section.

Comment: Thanks @ElectricShadow that seemed to fix the issue entirely! Thank you everyone else for your useful suggestions also